# lock rows in r as in excel

Tags: r, for-loop, row

I am testing R out and I am stuck with one problem. How to lock rows [cell] in r as I do in Excel.

Example: Dataset(dff)

```
   X   Y
  35   1
  18   2
  17   3
  35   4
```

I would like to do a nested for-loop where I would like to add 35 with 1 then with 2, 3 and 4. Once this is over then I will add 18 with 1,2,3,4 etc

To do that I need to do it in two steps:

Step 1: 
Create a matrix where the nested for-loop is stored

Outcome should look like this

```
   X   V1  V2 V3 V4
  35   36  19 18 36
  18   37  20 19 37
  17   38  21 20 38
  35   39  22 21 39
```

Each time I am simply adding row of X with Y rows

To do this I wrote this nested for-loop

```
  step1 = matrix(0, nrow=nrow(dff), ncol = nrow(dff)) #create a placeholder

  for (i in 1:nrow(dff[,1])) # for each row in the first column 
    for (j in 1:nrow(dff[,2])){ # for each row in the second column 
    add[i,j] =  i +j # add them in the placeholder
    }
```

Issue: 
I get an error stating:

```
  Error in 1:nrow(dff[, 1]) : argument of length 0
```

Step 2: Add sum of the step 1 columns to my original dataset(dff)

```
  dff <- cbind(dff, apply(add[,-1], 2,sum) # calculate the column sums of all except the X column, where 2 is refering to column
```

Please correct my nested for-loop and then provide additional ways of doing it or else I will never learn:) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `for` loops for this. Here you can use `outer` or, preferably, some simple maths:

```
DF <- data.frame(X = c(35, 18, 17, 35),
                 Y = 1:4)
outer(DF$Y, DF$X, "+")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   36   19   18   36
#[2,]   37   20   19   37
#[3,]   38   21   20   38
#[4,]   39   22   21   39

DF$Z <- colSums(outer(DF$Y, DF$X, "+"))
DF$Z1 <- nrow(DF) * DF$X + sum(DF$Y)
#   X Y   Z  Z1
#1 35 1 150 150
#2 18 2  82  82
#3 17 3  78  78
#4 35 4 150 150
```

Comment: Thanks and I will not use for-loop. But for my own understanding would kindly have a look at my for-loop and correct it? I really need to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `df[,1]` is a vector and thus doesn't have rows. You want `length(df[,1])`.

Answer (score 1):

I create your data frame as follows:

```
dff <- data.frame(X = c(35, 18, 17, 35), Y = 1:4)
```

And then I use `sapply()` to get the matrix that you show as the result of *Step 1*. The sum over the columns can then be calculated with `colSums()`:

```
mat <- sapply(seq_along(dff$X), function(i) dff$X[i] + dff$Y)
data.frame(dff, Z = colSums(mat))
##    X Y   Z
## 1 35 1 150
## 2 18 2  82
## 3 17 3  78
## 4 35 4 150
```

### Correcting the for-loop in the question

As was already pointed out by Roland, the main mistake with your for-loop is that you even try to solve this problem with a for-loop. But if you absolutely want to do it with a loop it is possible. There are several issues with your loop and I won't go into all of them. Just compare the following with your loop:

```
step1 = matrix(0, nrow=nrow(dff), ncol = nrow(dff)) #create a placeholder
for (i in 1:nrow(dff)) {# for each row in the first column 
  for (j in 1:nrow(dff)) { # for each row in the second column 
    step1[i, j] <-  dff$Y[i] + dff$X[j] # add them in the placeholder
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would kindly have a look at my for-loop and correct it? I really need to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `sapply(dff$X, function(x) x + dff$Y)` should be enough for step 1. Isn't it?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, that would give the same.